# Custom Post Type Date Based Archive URL rewrite

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, archives, rewrite-rules, custom-post-type-archives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [custom post types, wp_get_archives and add_rewrite_rule](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50530/custom-post-types-wp-get-archives-and-add-rewrite-rule)

I have a custom post type called "course" and I would like to create a date based archive similar to the default post archives which look like mysite.com/2012/05.

I want to use urls like mysite.com/**course**/2012/05.

How can I do this using the [WordPress rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)? While avoiding plugins.

This solution is very close [How to give a CPT (custom post type) a date based url](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19652/how-to-give-a-cpt-custom-post-type-a-date-based-url) but I would like to avoid using a query var if possible and stick with the year/month based urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had similar situation not long ago. [Check the answer to my question here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50530/custom-post-types-wp-get-archives-and-add-rewrite-rule). I believe that will solve your problem.